# SATA controller appears to slow down kernel compilation (8.48 minutes vs 1.30m when a SATA HD is disconnected)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel

OK, this is a weird one

When a SATA device such as a hard disk or a DVD-RW is connected to my box, linux kernel compilation (5.12.4) takes about 8 to 9 minutes on my Ryzen 5950x on a Samsung NVME 970 Evo and a 16GB RAM @ 3200 all installed on an AsRock b550 Taichi motherboard. The spinnable hard disk is merely connected to the SATA port on the motherboard and none of the partitions are mounted.

When I physically disconnect/unplug the HD from the motherboard's SATA port, exactly the same process (clean compilation, starting from a fresh new archive) takes about 1.30 minutes.

The same slow down appears even when I connect a DVD-RW but it does not occur when I connect an SSD to the SATA port.

I am absolutely perplexed, to me looks it looks like somehow the SATA controller on the chipset interferes with processor's speed when old-tech devices are connected.

Here are the commands I am running to compile the kernel:

```
tar xf linux-5.8.10.tar.gz
cd linux-5.8.10
cp /boot/config-`uname -r` .config
yes '' | make oldconfig
make clean
time make -j32 LOCALVERSION=-custom
```

I run Ubuntu 20.04. I have disconnected my HD and use it over USB now to avoid this slow down.

Answer (score 1):

You might have a bad SATA cable that picks up radio frequency interference from the other components inside the chassis, or otherwise generates spurious signals on the SATA connection. This keeps triggering the SATA controller and/or the OS to check on the status of the device, interfering with traffic on the motherboard data buses and/or wasting CPU time.

In such a case, I would expect the kernel to spew a lot of error messages to the kernel message buffer and/or system logs. Use the `dmesg` command to check the kernel messages; see if there are any SATA-related error messages.

Comment: thx, I am voting you up because what you said definitely makes sense and is plausible but I just resolved the issue by updating my BIOS/EFI from 1.80 to 1.90 (latest at the time of writing) which can be obtained from https://www.asrock.com/MB/AMD/B550%20Taichi/index.asp#BIOS - these 500x series chipsets have some issues here and there based on what I have read around, fortunately it appears to have resolved this issue too. Hopefully someone else find either of these posts useful.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue by updating my BIOS/EFI from 1.80 to 1.90 (latest at the time of writing) which can be obtained from asrock.com/MB/AMD/B550%20Taichi/index.asp#BIOS